# Twitter Bootstrap + Backbone.js + What UI Library?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) for my web applicaton but I need also to add a good looking Form and Grid. Form need to have a field validation, dropboxes and to insert/edit rows from grid. In the end I need to submit gird data using Ajax and JSON. Can you recomend me a library that can help me with this? May be [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/), [Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/overview/index.html)? Or may be something that integrates easy with Backbone.js and will not conflict with Twitter Bootstrap CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KendoUI is pretty awesome. Really clean interface that binds to data relatively easy.

Just this...

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
          columns:[
              {
                  field: "FirstName",
                  title: "First Name"
              },
              {
                  field: "LastName",
                  title: "Last Name"
          }],
          dataSource: {
              data: [
                  {
                      FirstName: "Joe",
                      LastName: "Smith"
                  },
                  {
                      FirstName: "Jane",
                      LastName: "Smith"
              }]
          }
      });
```

Will get you going with a grid in Kendo, hit up @burkeholland on Twitter if you need some help.

EXTJS is also awesome, but is much larger than Kendo and may be a little bit overkill for what you are looking for, however it's very powerful.

BackboneJS is going to require a lot of work to get your application's models, and validation stuff setup, but it is a very flexible, "MVC"-esque framework.

Really just depends on how complicated you want to get, and how much work you want to throw into it.

Comment: For clarification, Kendo UI additionally has it's own concept of models and views with templating.  Kind of like a "light" MVC.  You can use either, although you may find it easier to integrate using Kendo UI's built-in framework features.